# ModelState validation is not working for httppost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My entity frame work model state validation is not working i tried many thing but still its not working?

code=>

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private TsmsDBContext db = new TsmsDBContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        db.Users.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "UserId,password")] User user)
    {
        Response.Write((user.UserId + user.password).ToString());

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Response.Write((user.UserId+user.password).ToString());
        }

        return View(user);   
    }

}
```

http get index method is for showing login page?
and post is for just take userid and password and show it.but userid and password is showing before `if(ModelState.IsValid)`? but after it it is not showing.i thing everything is ok.but dont know why its not working?

my model class of USER=>

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User Id Cannot Be Empty")]
    [MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "You Have Exceed The Max length Of User ID which is [12] character")]
    [RegularExpression("[1-3]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[123]{1}|[1-3]{2}-[0-9]{7}-[123]{1}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Id,It should [xx]-[xxxxx]-[x] or [xx]-[xxxxxxx]-[x]")]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password Cannot Be Empty")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Password Max Length Is 20 Character")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ////////
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User Level Cannot Be Empty")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The Max Length For User Level Is 100 Character")]
    [Display(Name = "User Level")]
    public string level { get; set; }

    //relationship with other table----

    //public List<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

and my index view=>

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "form-control" , @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "form-control" , @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.password) })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
        <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

i thing may be its not working for some reason.so i tried to change=>

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
}
```

in state of  tag but not working.i also remove antiforgari token.but still not working?
any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ModelState` is not valid since you have the `level` property null for the `user` model

Add this to the HTML within the form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.level)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 error in your modelstate. Because you created required attribute in your model class `user` for `level`. But in your view you don't have any textbox or place to enter the level. So your `level` propety is null in this scenario. As Sajal suggested you should have it as hidden property.
Or you can clear the error for level property.